# Copying CSS into my index.css in React does not apply in my app

Tags: css, reactjs

So I'm following along the tutorial on Youtube about reactJS, and the youtuber told me to import a CSS file into my index.css then it should be properly showing rendering of the website, however, when i copied the CSS and imported into my App.js and Index.js nothing pops up, does anyone know how to deal with this? is the style are different for the versions of react? am I missing any other set up?

here is index.css:

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@300;400&display=swap');


* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Poppins', sans-serif;
}

.container {
  max-width: 500px;
  margin: 30px auto;
  overflow: auto;
  min-height: 300px;
  border: 1px solid steelblue;
  padding: 30px;
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.btn {
  display: inline-block;
  background: #000;
  color: #fff;
  border: none;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  margin: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-family: inherit;
}

.btn:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.btn:active {
  transform: scale(0.98);
}

.btn-block {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
}

.task {
  background: #f4f4f4;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.task.reminder {
  border-left: 5px solid green;
}

.task h3 {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.add-form {
  margin-bottom: 40px;
}

.form-control {
  margin: 20px 0;
}

.form-control label {
  display: block;
}

.form-control input {
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 3px 7px;
  font-size: 17px;
}

.form-control-check {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.form-control-check label {
  flex: 1;
}

.form-control-check input {
  flex: 2;
  height: 20px;
}

footer {
  margin-top: 30px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Here is my App.js and Index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import './index.css';

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
    <App />
);

// If you want to start measuring performance in your app, pass a function
// to log results (for example: reportWebVitals(console.log))
// or send to an analytics endpoint.
reportWebVitals();
```

Lastly, App.js :

```
import Header from "./components/Header";
import Tasks from "./components/Tasks";
import './index.css';


function App() {
  return (
    <div className="Container">
      <Header title='Orpheus Research'/>
      <Tasks />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App
```

Comment: Is your index.css file definitely in the path you are declaring it to be in?

Comment: "_am I missing any other set up?_": sounds likely, if you can share how you have set up your React project and your configuration files, that would greatly help pinpointing the issue. Ideally share a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The index.css should be imported into the index.js file. So you can just delete the import in the app.js.

Since you import with "./index.css" as the path you need to make sure that the index.css file is in the same folder (I suppose it's the src folder) as the index.js.

Comment: My answer was too naive to be heard it's because of i named my container elements in capital letters...Though I def agree with FocusCookie's answer we definitely have to check for the folders and path to identify we're using the correct ones, it's the hint of tracing my filespath names that led me to this error. Thanks greatly, again.